# How many odd numbers with distinct digits between 1000 and 9999

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers with distinct digits are there between 1000 and 9999. [1]

I came up with a solution like this.

Since we can't know what numbers have been used, in the tens, hundreds and thousands we start counting at the ones.

```
1s:     { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, so 5 initial possibilities
10s:    { 0, 1, ... , 9 }, so 10 initial possibilities, 1 taken: 9 left
100s:   { 0, 1, ... , 9 }, so 10 initial possibilities, 2 taken: 8 left
1000s:  { 1, 2, ... , 9 }, so 9 initial possibilites, 3 taken: 6 left
```

So then we arrive at the following: 5 * 9 * 8 * 6 = 2160 possibilities. I thought this was pretty straight forward.

Than I had a glimpse at the solution sheet... And lo an answer which really doesn't make much sense at its first glimpse.

> Calculate the sum of those odd numbers with distinct digits with no 0’s, a 0 in
>   the tens place, or a 0 in the hundreds place. No 0’s: 5 choices for the ones place,
>   then 8 · 7 · 6 choices for the other three places; 0 in the tens place: 5 choices for the
>   ones place and 1 choice for the tens place, then 8 · 7 choices for the other two
>   places; 0 in the hundreds place: 5 choices for the ones place and 1 choice for the
>   hundreds place, then 8 · 7 choices for the other two places;
>
> (5 · 8 · 7 · 6) + (5 · 1 · 8 · 7) + (5 · 1 · 8 · 7) = 2240;

Why are the 0's treated special? The exercise states it should be an odd number, with distinct digits. I thought I adhered to that proposition....

[1] Exercise 2.7.15 from Applied Combinatorics 2nd edition by Fred S. Roberts and Barry Tesman

Comment: That 6 left implies that the 0 is not taken as if it is then there are 7 possible values for the first digit which you are missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes when you assume that there were $3$ taken from your last set. It's quite possible that the second or third choice was a $0$, so that you in fact have only eliminated $2$ options from the last set.

Instead, choose the last digit first ($5$ choices), then the first digit ($8$ choices, since we can't have picked $0$ for the last digit), then deal with the second and third digit ($8$ and $7$ choices, in some order). That will get you $5\cdot 8\cdot 8\cdot 7=2240$, as desired.

Comment: Of course! Very clear now. Just like I had treated the odd numbers at first! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If a $0$ is taken for one of the "middle" digits, that gives a different number of possibilities for the $1000$'s digit than if $0$ is not used as a middle digit.

One could deal with that by dividing into cases, but the following is more efficient:

There are $5$ choices for the last digit. For each of these choices there are $8$ choices for the lead digit. Then for the middle digits we have $8\cdot 7$ choices.

Answer (score 0):

Consider picking 4 digits out of a bucket of 10 $\begin{pmatrix} 0, 1, 2,3, ...\end{pmatrix}$ and arranging them.

There are $${10 P_4 = 5040} $$ ways to pick these digits & arrange them $(210\times 24)$ to be exact because there are 24 permutations per selection.

Of these, you reject $${9 P_3 = 504}$$ of these digits because you do not want $0$ as the first digit...so consider picking 3 digits out of a bucket of 9 and arranging them.

All you need to do is simple subtraction to get $5040 - 504 = 4536$

Comment: Okay, this is just a small hint because it is only for all numbers...you need to pick a subset for only odd numbers...but the idea is about the same.